# How to update npm modules, ignoring a git repo

Tags: git, npm

I forked one of npm modules and now it is a git repo.

So my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "some-module": "git+https://github.com/my-name/some-module.git",
}
```

Forked repo is synchronized by fetching upstream and merging.
But when I try to update other npm modules it gives error:

```
npm ERR! git Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /Users/.../node_modules/some-module
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/...
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/.../node_modules/some-module
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.../npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Is there any way to ignore git repo when updating? Or to skip this error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

npm checks all directories for the existance of a `.git` directory, and throws the `EISGIT` error if it exists, so there is no way to ignore it or skip it.

The [code](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/f2ae3baf9e4b48282bcfceb94ce861b9221450d0/lib/install/validate-tree.js#L24) does however check if it's a link:

```
mod.parent && !mod.isLink && [checkGit, mod.realpath],
```

So I was able to make it work by symlinking the module into node_modules.

```
$ ln -s ../some-module node_modules
```

Comment: Either of the following worked for me in Windows: `mklink /D "node_modules/some-module" "../some-module"` or `mklink /J "node_modules/some-module" "../some-module"`

Comment: In my case, I was using Watchman Links (WML) to simulate a symlink between a git managed library and a React Native project. I simply excluding the .git folder from the WML link and deleted the .git from the lib in the RN project's node_modules. Npm install/update worked as expected.

Comment: I also tried symlinking my modules folder to the node_modules directory but i still get an error when I try to install a new module:
enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Volumes/Web-Projects/_intern/marten/my-project/node_modules/my-module'

Comment: You are my personal hero now `ln -s` perfectly does the job

Comment: Good catch reading that code, thanks! @MartenZander you created the symbolic while being on your app root folder. Move in *node_modules*, then `ln -s` with the relative path from there.

Answer (score 16):

I too had this issue whilst doing an npm install library and I was able to solve it by removing the `.git` directory (which is hidden inside `node_modules/library_name`) from the corresponding library_name mentioned in the error message.

Also make sure you don't delete the `.git directory` from the root of your project because if you delete the .git directory from the project root you will lose git related info like branch info,etc

Thanks to [bolav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36129219/5706413) for good a explanation regarding how the EISGIT error is thrown.

Comment: you saved my day. This works. For other who does not know how to delete, please type the following code: rm -rf .git
Make sure you are in the correct module folder.

Comment: I have `.github` repo, `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` in my module. But I don't have a `.git`. Should I delete any of those mentioned?

Comment: checked for .git file inside the node_modules/liberary name? it might be a hidden file..... dont delete any other file,only delete the .git file inside node_modules/liberary name.......

Answer (score 7):

```
rm -rf node_modules/*/.git/
```

Try this

Sometimes -rf command gives error then try this:

```
rm -r node_modules/*/.git/
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a way to skip the error.

1) Open the file "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-install-checks\index.js"
2) Comment out this code at the very bottom:

```
if (!er && s.isDirectory()) {
  var e = new Error(folder + ': Appears to be a git repo or submodule.')
  e.path = folder
  e.code = 'EISGIT'
  return cb(e)
}
```

Done.

### Background

From another dev long frustrated by this error; none of the suggested solutions work in my case because of constraints from various systems.

Suggestion: NPM works with symlinks, so create symlink of module from node_modules, to your library repo folder.
Problem: Then Watchman doesn't scan the JS files within.

Suggestion: Do "npm publish" and "npm install". Every. Single. Time.
Problem: Terrible for quick development tests/cycles, and spams the npm directory with hundreds of never-to-be-used versions.

Suggestion: Use Watchman Links (WML). (i.e. directory auto-copying on file-change)
Problem: Have to have a background program running all the time, for all the included repos on my machine. Also, it means I can't open the files directly in the node_modules folder to make quick changes; instead I have to go to the library's source repo every time. That's fine usually, but sometimes it's nice to make changes in the program repo, and have it reflected in the library repo, in addition to vice-versa.

### My solution

So yeah, with the above change, I can use a hard-link clone of the library directory and avoid the problems above.

I use this to create the directory-level hard-link clone: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html#hardlinkclones

The one problem with this approach is that I have to re-run the hard-link clone whenever I add or remove files in the library. But at least I don't have to do anything when changes are made within existing files. (which is by far more painful)

Answer (score -3):

KISHOREs-MBP:dummyReactNativeProject simpro$ npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR! path /Users/simpro/Desktop/Kishore/dummyReactNativeProject/node_modules/**react-native-safe-area-view**
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git /Users/simpro/Desktop/Kishore/dummyReactNativeProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /Users/simpro/Desktop/Kishore/dummyReactNativeProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/simpro/.npm/_logs/2019-05-10T10_29_18_510Z-debug.log
KISHOREs-MBP:dummyReactNativeProject simpro$ rm -rf .git
KISHOREs-MBP:dummyReactNativeProject simpro$ npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR! path /Users/simpro/Desktop/Kishore/dummyReactNativeProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git /Users/simpro/Desktop/Kishore/dummyReactNativeProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /Users/simpro/Desktop/Kishore/dummyReactNativeProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/simpro/.npm/_logs/2019-05-10T10_33_07_251Z-debug.log

I was also facing same issue while installing react-native-gesture-handler.
then i removed **react-native-safe-area-view**(this was the folder giving issue) from node modules and installed react-native-gesture-handler and worked for me.

Reason:due to git