# Trying to install node modules via "npm install" causes error "git Appears to be a git repo or submodule."

Tags: node.js, git, npm, node-modules, postcss

I am currently developing a new PostCSS Plugin and therefore I create a new node_module subfolder. I made this subfolder a git repo, to share and publish the plugin.
When I am trying to install further modules to the project via "npm install" (gulp-watch in this case) I get the following error.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0 npm ERR! argv "/Users/marten/.nvm/v5.5.0/bin/node" "/Users/marten/.nvm/v5.5.0/bin/npm" "i" "gulp-watch" "-D"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /Volumes/Web-Projects/_intern/marten/postcss-random/node_modules/postcss-random
npm ERR! code EISGIT

npm ERR! git Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git /Volumes/Web-Projects/_intern/marten/postcss-random/node_modules/postcss-random
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Volumes/Web-Projects/_intern/marten/postcss-random/npm-debug.log
```

Is there any workarround for this particular problem? Can I tell npm to ignore my postcss plugin folder and to not try to remove it?

Comment: You shouldn't create a git repository inside the `node_modules` subfolder. Use `npm` for that.

Comment: @AxelIsouard What should I use npm for? to push the files to git? Sorry I am new to both, git and npm...

Comment: Yes, there is a way to bypass the error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40891438/2441655